# Trying to build Spring Webflow Travel Sample With the PrimeFaces Components and getting errors

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, primefaces, spring-webflow

I am trying to build Spring Webflow Travel Sample With the PrimeFaces Components and getting errors..

The following are the steps I am taking:

```
svn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/webflow-primefaces-showcase
cd webflow-primefaces-showcase
mvn package
```

Here are the errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project webflow-primefaces-showcase: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.samples:webflow-primefaces-showcase:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.M1-SNAPSHOT in org.springframework.maven.snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Here is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>webflow-primefaces-showcase</artifactId>
    <name>JSF 2, Spring Web Flow, and PrimeFaces Showcase</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.5</java-version>
        <springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</springframework-version>
        <springwebflow-version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</springwebflow-version>
        <springsecurity-version>3.0.3.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>${springwebflow-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF-303 Dependency Injection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Sun Mojarra JSF 2 runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PrimeFaces component library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.M1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSR 303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>  
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Hibernate Validator -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>         
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>         
        </repository>       
        <!-- For Sun Mojarra JSF 2 implementation -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>         
        </repository>
        <!-- For PrimeFaces JSF component library -->
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Technology Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.prime.com.tr</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>       
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <sourceExcludes>
                        <sourceExclude>**/.svn/**</sourceExclude>
                    </sourceExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
            </plugin>                       
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this repository

```
<repository>  
    <id>prime-repo</id>  
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
    <layout>default</layout>  
</repository>
```

Comment: i am still getting: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project webflow-primefaces-showcase: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.samples:webflow-primefaces-showcase:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.M1-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: If you get access to web over proxy you have to set it in setting.xml of maven. Make sure you do this in USER_HOME/.m2/settings.xml and MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml. Remove from repository in USER_HOME/.m2/repository/ this librarys which is containad in pom.xml dependencies(or evry one library contained in your local repository- maven download its after automaticaly). After this make mvn package. If you add mentioned repository maven should download correct librarys

Comment: Every library contained in your pom dependencies is available in maven central repository, so rest repository excluding mentioned by me is useless

Answer (score 2):

I had to add this change to the **pom.xml** to have the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i had to do both. but now the project runs but I am getting errors. like: Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

Comment: in evry page where you use primefaces component you declare namespace in html tag change it to xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui", but when you change version from 2 to 3 i'am not sure that every component from 2 will be compatible in primefaces 3.4.1 which is newest release

Comment: so what do you think i should try? are you using primefaces with spring web flow

Comment: i develop 2 projects with primefaces and spring webflow actually. in my opinion with this project you shuld back to primefaces 2.2 but not to version 2.2.M1-SNAPSHOT which is not available in primefaces reopository. i see you try run a some sample so dowload from here http://springsource.org/spring-web-flow#download zip spring-webflow-2.3.1.RELEASE-with-dependencies and in path spring-webflow-2.3.1.RELEASE\projects\spring-webflow-samples\booking-faces it's good project to start with primefacesAndSpring-webflow. Make 'mvn eclipse:eclipse clean package' importToEclipse configure->maven andDeploy

Comment: please post the URL to the sample of the booking you are talking about... what do you like better Dojo or PrimeFaces..  are you on twitter?? findme JohnathanMSmith